# PHP: Malformed header

Tags: php, http-headers, bad-request

Could someone explain what is wrong with this PHP code? (PHP Version 5.3.5)

```
<?php 
    header('Bad Request', true, 400);
    exit;
```

I get a status 500 instead of 400. And in the apache error log I get

> malformed header from script. Bad header=Bad Request: listener.php

What am I doing wrong here? Have I misunderstood [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you have to write:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
```

Comment: Thank you! Why couldn't it just have figured that out on it's own... *sigh*

Comment: I find that you don't really need the two optional parameters for HTTP response codes - `header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request')` works just as well.

Comment: @HorusKol, Yeah, but I must say I find that quite dumb. The status code is the only thing that should have to be required. Shouldn't PHP know the right text and stuff itself kind of?

Comment: "Forces the HTTP response code to the specified value. Note that this parameter **only has an effect if the string is not empty.**" http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php